# MySql Left Join slow when adding and or clause

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have a problem with the performance of a query. I have the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT anuncios.id, precios.precio
FROM anuncios
LEFT JOIN precios ON ( (
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.idcentro
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
) )
GROUP BY anuncios.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

that spends 0.001 seg. On the other hand I have this one, very similar:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT anuncios.id, precios.precio
FROM anuncios
LEFT JOIN precios ON ( 
(
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.id
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
) )
GROUP BY anuncios.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

that also spends the same time, more or less. The problem is when I combine both queries into this one:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT anuncios.id, precios.precio
FROM anuncios
LEFT JOIN precios ON ( (
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.idcentro
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
)
OR (
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.id
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
) )
GROUP BY anuncios.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here the execution time multiplies by 100.

Theese are both tables desciption:

Precios:

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usuario           | varchar(40)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tipocentroanuncio | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idcentroanuncio   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| unidades          | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tipounidades      | varchar(15)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| precio            | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| otrosdatosprecio  | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| principal         | int(1) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

anuncios:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+------
```

and this is the explain of the query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows Extra
1   SIMPLE  anuncios    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1048578     Using temporary; Using filesort

1   SIMPLE  precios     index   idcentroanuncio     idcentroanuncio     156 NULL    30  Using index
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it logical this time increase combining two querys that run fast independently?

Comment: not necessarily it will speed up ...using OR statement even with indexed column can be killer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You have learned the `or` can really mess up execution plans.  Try using `union` instead:

```
SELECT a.id, p.precio
FROM anuncios a LEFT JOIN
     precios p
     ON p.idcentroanuncio = a.idcentro AND
        a.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio' AND 
        p.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
UNION
SELECT a.id, p.precio
FROM anuncios a LEFT JOIN
     precios p
     ON p.idcentroanuncio = a.id AND
        a.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio' AND
        p.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Some notes and then a better query.  First, you don't need `distinct` when you have `group by`.  Second, this version doesn't need `group by` or `distinct`, because the `union` takes care of making the values distinct.

For performance, you may be able to take a different route.  Try this:

```
select p.idcentroanuncio, p.price
from precios p
where p.tipocentroanuncio = 'centro' and
      (exists (select 1
               from annuncios a
               where p.idcentroanuncio = a.id and a.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
              ) or
       exists (select 1
               from annuncios a
               where p.idcentroanuncio = a.idcentro and a.tipoubicacion = 'centropropio'
              )
      );
```

This may eliminate the need for the `distinct`.  And the subqueries can each take advantage of an index:  `annuncios(id, tipoubicacion)` and `annuncios(idcentro, tipoubicacion)`.

Comment: sorry, the idea was to also show the prices. I've reduced de original query to the max to find the problem. I update the querys. I'll try what you suggest with Union clause.

Comment: @oskar . . . You can add `price` to the first query to get what you want.

Comment: The first point seems to work properly, just adapting a pair of things. This seems to be the correct query:

SELECT anuncios.id, precios.precio
FROM anuncios
LEFT JOIN precios ON ( (
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.idcentro
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion =  'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio =  'centro'
) ) 
GROUP BY anuncios.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
UNION 
SELECT anuncios.id, precios.precio
FROM anuncios
LEFT JOIN precios ON ( (
precios.idcentroanuncio = anuncios.id
AND anuncios.tipoubicacion =  'centropropio'
AND precios.tipocentroanuncio =  'centro'
) ) 
GROUP BY anuncios.id
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Basically I must add the group by on both subqueries, if not it repeats some results.

Many thanks!